# Spring redirect in controller shows error

Tags: java, spring

The redirect not working in spring, Any special annotation needed for this? Whats wrong in the below code. please help !!

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/logout") 
public String logout() throws IOException {
            setLoggedInUser(null);
        return "redirect:/index";
        }
```

When  i logout i have to redirect it to another url and i have given the function as shown above. Still it is not redirecting to that action. What will be the reason? please help..

Comment: remove /index from redirect:, it will automatically redirect to the index file if its in your webcontent root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have any prefix added in web.xml as shown below

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

If prefix exists change your code to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/logout") 
public String logout() throws IOException {
            setLoggedInUser(null);
        return "redirect:/index.do";
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the link you given is correct or not? also check if there is controller for this url.

There is  no special annotation you hvae to use for the redirect to work.